# Tensorflow: PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge: 2 vs. 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using keras with tf-2.2 at backend and it shows up this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 97, in <module>
    task_entry_function()
  File "/data-crystina/src/capreolus-unpublished/capreolus/task/rerank.py", line 47, in train
    return self.rerank_run(best_search_run, self.get_results_path())
  File "/data-crystina/src/capreolus-unpublished/capreolus/task/rerank.py", line 85, in rerank_run
    self.benchmark.relevance_level,
  File "/data-crystina/src/capreolus-unpublished/capreolus/trainer/__init__.py", line 578, in train
    use_multiprocessing=True,
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 855, in fit
    callbacks.on_train_batch_end(step, logs)
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 389, in on_train_batch_end
    logs = self._process_logs(logs)
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 265, in _process_logs
    return tf_utils.to_numpy_or_python_type(logs)                                                                                                                                                             File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py", line 523, in to_numpy_or_python_type
    return nest.map_structure(_to_single_numpy_or_python_type, tensors)
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 617, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 617, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/tf_utils.py", line 519, in _to_single_numpy_or_python_type
    x = t.numpy()
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 961, in numpy
    maybe_arr = self._numpy()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/data-crystina/anaconda3/envs/maxp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 929, in _numpy
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __inference_train_function_100056}} PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge: 2 vs. 1
         [[{{node map_6/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack}}]]
         [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
         [[RemoteCall]]
         [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
2020-07-03 07:19:03.088112: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/remote_tensor_handle_data.cc:76] Unable to destroy remote tensor handles. If you are running a tf.function, it usually indicates som
e op in the graph gets an error: {{function_node __inference_train_function_100056}} PartialTensorShape: Incompatible ranks during merge: 2 vs. 1
         [[{{node map_6/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack}}]]
         [[MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard]]
         [[RemoteCall]]
         [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]]
```

Apologize for failing to find a small snippet to reproduce this. But I go inside `..python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py`, and in the function:

```
  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    """Calls the `on_train_batch_end` methods of its callbacks.

    Arguments:
        batch: integer, index of batch within the current epoch.
        logs: dict. Metric results for this batch.
    """
    if self._should_call_train_batch_hooks:
      # print("<<<<", logs.keys())
      # print(">>>", type(list(logs.values())[0]))
      logs = self._process_logs(logs)
      self._call_batch_hook(ModeKeys.TRAIN, 'end', batch, logs=logs)
```

I print out the `logs` and found it's a dictionary containing only one key `loss`, and the type of its value is `class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`. However, the `logs["loss"]` cannot be printed directory because of the same error, and same to `logs["loss"].shape`. I failed to find any similar case in internet, wondering whether anyone has met this case?

Comment: It's very hard to help you with this information, even if someone has come up against a similar error, I think the solution will very much depend on your specific code. The error says `If you are running a tf.function, it usually indicates some op in the graph gets an error`, Keras will run things as a `tf.function` afaik, so probably there is some bit in your code that is causing some issue at some point, which is later reflected in the error you are seeing. If you have any custom TensorFlow code (besides standard Keras layers), try commenting and uncommenting things to isolate the cause...

Comment: thanks! I got it solved with my friend's help, so it rooted from I'm trying to parse the tfrecord using a wrong shape/data type. it says tf.function maybe because the `parse_tfrecord` function is passed into tf.map or something xd

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it's totally because I'm trying to parse the tfrecord using a wrong shape/data type in a callback passed to TensorFlow.